# Nested loop and functional programming

Tags: f#

Please consider a C program that, given `x`, will return `y` and `z` such that `y + z * 2 = x`, for the smallest possible `y`. Roughly, I could create a nested loop:

```
for(y = 0; y < x; ++ y){
    for(z = 0; z < x; ++z){
        if(y + 2 * z == x){
            printf("%d + 2 * %d = %d", y, z, x);
        }
    }
}
```

How could I translate this kind of nested loop in *the functional way*? Is it feasible? Is it *reasonable* or am I just misjudging the approach? My best attempt so far:

```
let foo x =
    let rec aux (y, z, q) =
        match (y + z * 2) with
        r when r = q -> (y, z)
        |_      -> aux(y + 1, z + 1, q)  //How to check different values of z
    aux(0, 0, x)                         //for each value of y?
```

It will not work, since it will just increment both `y` and `z`. How can I check different values of z, for every value of y?

Comment: Procedural languages (like C) and a functional language (like F#) are representing two different paradigms when it comes to programming. As such you can't really do direct translations between them (well you *can* but it won't be good translations, most likely quite the opposite), you often have to *think* differently.

Comment: As for the question in the comment of your functional snippet -> use a second recursive function.

Comment: assuming this is about unsigned integers, why don't you calculate the result directly? `y =  x%2; z = x/2` would do .... (and can be expressed in functional code)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to add those checks in the match.

See here what your code is missing:

```
let foo x =
    let rec aux (y, z, q) =
        match (y + z * 2) with
        | r when r = q -> (y, z)
        | _ when y = q -> failwith "not found !"
        | _ when z = q -> aux (y + 1, 0, q)
        | _            -> aux (y, z + 1, q)
    aux (0, 0, x)
```

And here's a different approach, equally functional but without recursion:

```
let foo2 x =
    let s =
        {0 .. x} |> Seq.collect (fun y ->
            {0 .. x} |> Seq.collect (fun z -> 
                seq [y, z]))
    Seq.find (fun (y, z) -> y + z * 2 = x) s
```

which in F# can be written using seq expressions:

```
let foo3 x =
    let s = seq {
        for y in {0 .. x} do
            for z in {0 .. x} do
                yield (y, z)}
    Seq.find (fun (y, z) -> y + z * 2 = x) s
```

and it resembles your original C program.

Comment: You don't need the brackets. "for y in 0 .. x do" works equally well.

Comment: Thanks Gustavo, your examples are helping me to clarify several concepts. I am doing practice on them! I have just a question. In your first snippet, what is r? I am not sire I got it correctly. Does it has a value? Is it just a name?

Comment: @Worice Actually ``r`` comes from your code, not mine. But yes, it contains the result of evaluating ``(y + z * 2)``. If you ask me I would re-write that match or use an if then elif expression instead, but I just wanted to stick as much as possible to your code and show you what you were missing.